# Inicializando o Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Tenho um pequeno problema ao inicializar meu Redmine no ambiente. Após toda a configuração do Mysql etc... quando uso o comando para start da aplicação recebo a mensagem:

```
ArgumentError (A secret is required to generate an integrity hash for cookie session data. Use config.secret_token = "some secret phrase of
at least 30 characters"in config/initializers/secret_token.rb):
```

Alguma idéia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Não conheço ruby, mas pela mensagem diz que vc deve configurar o arquivo config/initializers/secret_token.rb setando um token em "config.secret_token".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O arquivo `secret_token.rb` inicialmente está ausente. Ao instalar, você deve gerá-lo usando:

```
rake generate_secret_token
```

Deve ser possível criá-lo à mão também, <del>mas não conheço o formato</del> (ver atualização abaixo). Esse comando criará o arquivo no formato certo, com um token aleatório, de modo que é preferível.

Após criado, lembre-se que o `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` deve ser mantido confidencial - pois qualquer um que tiver acesso ao seu conteúdo poderia por exemplo forjar os dados de sessão. Se estiver num ambiente *NIX, colocar as permissões `600` (leitura e escrita pelo dono, nada pelos demais). E, obviamente, esse arquivo não deve ir para o controle de versões - cada instalação diferente deve ter o seu.

**Atualização**: conforme o [código-fonte do redmine](https://bitbucket.org/redmine/redmine-all/src/6ada0e6213f85e6be42f2ceadbec9b6ee8983ff4/lib/tasks/initializers.rake?at=default), o arquivo `secret_token.rb` que é gerado por esse comando possui o seguinte formato:

```ruby
# This file was generated by 'rake generate_secret_token', and should
# not be made visible to public.
# If you have a load-balancing Redmine cluster, you will need to use the
# same version of this file on each machine. And be sure to restart your
# server when you modify this file.
#
# Your secret key for verifying cookie session data integrity. If you
# change this key, all old sessions will become invalid! Make sure the
# secret is at least 30 characters and all random, no regular words or
# you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
RedmineApp::Application.config.secret_token = '#{secret}'
```

Onde `secret` é definido dessa forma:

```ruby
secret = SecureRandom.hex(40)
```

Então, se tiver problemas para executar o `generate_secret_token` você pode criar esse arquivo à mão, substituindo `'#{secret}'` por uma string longa e aleatóra.

Comment: Acho que essa resposta está errada, não existe essa tarefa no rake.

Comment: @Ricardo Aqui estão as referências que eu usei: [RedmineUpgrade](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade#Option-1-Downloaded-release-targz-or-zip-file) e [esse post no fórum do Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/30605). Talvez estejam desatualizadas.

Comment: @Ricardo Achei também no código-fonte do Redmine [a parte onde ele define `generate_secret_token`](https://bitbucket.org/redmine/redmine-all/src/6ada0e6213f85e6be42f2ceadbec9b6ee8983ff4/lib/tasks/initializers.rake?at=default). Vou atualizar a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Gere uma hash para o secret token utilizando o rake:

```
rake secret
```